# Using Flow & Login Flows to show my release notification

Tags: visual-workflow, flow, loginflow

I'm creating a visual workflow & login flow so that my users see a release notification before each deployment. I only want them to see the notification once, instead of every time they log in, which is where I'm running into a roadblock.

I created a custom checkbox on user called "Release Notification Seen?" and only want the release notification to be show to the user if it's unchecked (or FALSE).

So, for my flow I started with a Record Lookup that looks up the user who's running the flow. I then store the "Release Notification Seen" field in a variable. My next step is a decision where I move onto the next step ONLY IF "Release Notification Seen"  is FALSE. Then, I show the notification screen. Finally, I update the release notification field to be TRUE for that user when the flow finishes.

The thing that's happening is that my users are always logged in without seeing the notification, regardless of the value in the release notification field.

Any ideas why my flow isn't correctly recognizing that the release notification field is un-checked?

[image]

UPDATE:

Here are a few images that show the contents of the flow:

This image shows how I lookup the User and then assign the Release Notification field to a variable

[image: This image shows how I lookup the User and then assign the Release Notification field to a variable]

This image shows the decision contents
[image: This image shows the decision contents]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You named your Flow input variable wrong to get the Flow User ID. The proper format for that input variable should be `LoginFlow_UserId` as noted in [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Login-Flows) support article. It's not working because you aren't actually passing that users ID to the Flow, so it will never return the values you want from the User record.

> The following input attributes are supported:
>   LoginFlow_LoginType
>   LoginFlow_IpAddress
>   LoginFlow_UserAgent
>   LoginFlow_Platform
>   LoginFlow_Application
>   LoginFlow_Community
>   LoginFlow_SessionLevel
>   LoginFlow_UserId

Change the name of your variable to `LoginFlow_UserId` and everything should work just fine.

[image]

Comment: Oops -- hate it when typos ruin the whole process! That fixed it. Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem. Feel free post if you run into any more snags.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to assign the value of "Release Notification Seen?" to a variable. Use the variable in your Decision step. Alternatively you can have a "Assignment" step between Record lookup and Decision.

Comment: Hey, thanks. I did set the release notification field to a variable. I added a picture above to show the contents of my Record Lookup where this happens. Does anything look off to you?

Answer (score 0):

So, I agree with SL man and say that you might not be doing something right with your assignment of the variable and use in the decision... however, I am going to go off on a limb and say that is not whats going on.

I believe the issue you might be having is that you hid this field from the users?  Flow runs from the User's perspective. They'll need Read/Write on this field for you to do this.  You'll need to hide it from the Page Layout because of that (unless that isn't a big deal to you).  But, because its not triggered by Process Builder, it isn't run in the SYSTEM perspective and its based on that individual Profile's Field Level Security

Comment: Hey, the user's profile actually does have access to the release notification field. FYI - I added a few pictures above to give more info around how the flow is structured.